# Var attribute is not working on second page on OnsenUI

Tags: onsen-ui

I have two ons-carousel (v1.3.13) on two pages, I try to attach to the events but the carousel on the second page is not accessible in angular.

This is the js code

```
var app = ons.bootstrap();

app.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {
    console.log('ready 1');
    $scope.car1.on('overscroll', function(event) {

    });
  });
  $scope.foo = function() {
    navi.pushPage('page2.html');
  }
});

app.controller('DemoController2', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {
    console.log('ready 2');
    $scope.car2.on('overscroll', function(event) {

    });
  });
});
```

and Html code

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.slidingMenu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1" side="left" type="overlay" max-slide-distance="200px">
    </ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page1">
  <ons-navigator var="navi">
    <ons-page ng-controller="DemoController">
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Page 1</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
     <ons-button ng-click="foo()">Go To Page2</ons-button>
      <ons-carousel var="car1" style="width:100%;height:250px;" swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll auto-refresh>
        <ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel-item>
        <ons-carousel-cover>
          <div class="cover-label">Car1</div>
        </ons-carousel-cover>
      </ons-carousel>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="page2.html">

  <ons-page ng-controller="DemoController2">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 2</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-carousel var="car2" style="width:100%;height:250px;" swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll auto-refresh>
      <ons-carousel-item>
      </ons-carousel-item>
      <ons-carousel-cover>
        <div class="cover-label">Car2</div>
      </ons-carousel-cover>
    </ons-carousel>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-page>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOXxLQ) for my problem.

When trying to push page2 it shows error on console while the same code has no problem in page 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ons.ready` is only fired at the beginning of the app when the library is ready, not when a new controller is run afterwards. So it is actually not waiting for anything in `DemoController2`. You can use `pageinit` event instead: `document.addEventListener('pageinit', function($scope) { $scope.car2.on('overscroll', ... });`.

You can also use attribute [`ons-overscroll="expression"`](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#attributes), what is usually easier.

Comment: But look at the console, `ready 2` is print there, it means that the ons.ready is called, it try the solution for ons-overscroll and let you know the result

Comment: `ons-overscroll="handler($event)"` works but why I cannot access the variable in the controller?

Comment: How can I call `setActiveCarouselItemIndex(index)`?

Comment: With `ons.ready` in this case it enters the function but it doesn't wait, it enters directly so the variable is not defined yet. If you use `pageinit` event instead it will wait until the page is initialized. If you do it like that the variable will be defined and you can use it to call `setActiveCarouselItemIndex(index)`.